How to use yarn link as npm link in yarn 3?
I know that there are some related posts but I cannot find proper way to use yarn link in my project. I use yarn 3.5.
I got structure
Projects:

LibA
LibB

Package.json
And separate app
Where I should call yarn link and what parameters should I use ?

Can you edit the question to clarify what is being linked from and what is being linked to? What is the directory structure? What is the end result you want to achieve?
